# Testing Custom Functions

Tags: office-js, office-addins, yeoman, custom-functions-excel, excel-web-addins

After building a project and installing all the required dependencies, uploading the manifest of an Excel custom function over excel-web produces an error.

The excel custom function is a yeoman generated office add-in which has custom functions according to our needs. After the functions are created, we needed to test the functions on different platforms. We tried to upload the manifest onto excel-web, but it gives an Add-in error.

The manifest has been validated.

We have validated the manifest, and it passed all the test but while side-loading it on excel-web, there is an add-in error which prevents any of the custom functions from working.

We have used Excel custom functions along with angular framework. The project working fine on local environment, but we want to try out our custom functions on other platforms. We are facing issue while side-loading it on excel-web.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers: Again, **I did not and have not removed any image**, so again you are making false accusations. If I **had** removed the image, it would have been entirely appropriate, because we don't want images of **code, data or errors**. Have you learned to follow a link yet?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following steps to sideload local add-in to Excel on the web:

1. **run the following command in the root directory of your local add-in project to start the dev server.**

```
  npm run dev-server
```

2. Open Excel on the web. Open a document in Excel.
3. On the Insert tab, click the Add-ins section.
4. On the Office Add-ins dialog, select the MY ADD-INS tab (selected by default), choose Manage My Add-ins, and then Upload My Add-in.
5. The Office Add-ins dialog with a drop-down in the upper right reading "Manage my add-ins" and a drop-down below it with the option "Upload My Add-in".
6. Browse to the add-in manifest file, and then select Upload.
7. Verify that your add-in is installed.